# What happens when type dead key "acute accent" then "o" to produce "ó"?

Tags: x11, xkb, dead-keys

I'm on Belgian keyboard (`/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/be`) and when I type <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>ù</kbd> it produces the dead key "acute accent", it waits for another key, <kbd>o</kbd> for example, to produce `ó`.

How can I change which character is produced, such that I can do `´` + `o` = `ɔ` or anything I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is determined by the [compose mappings](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man5/Compose.5.xhtml). You can find your default mappings by looking up your locale in `/usr/share/X11/locale/compose.dir`, then checking the corresponding file, probably `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose`.

To override a compose sequence, create a file named `~/.XCompose`, enter

```
include "%L"
```

as its first line (this includes the default mappings), then add your own after that:

```
<dead_acute> <o> : "ɔ"
```

You can verify your changes by starting a new `xterm`: it will reflect the settings on startup. Other X programs might not; for example I’ve seen GNOME Terminal pick changes up, but not systematically, even when restarting it.

Comment: WDYM by `starting a new xterm` ? What is a `xterm` ? What does `%L` mean in that context ?

Comment: `xterm` is a terminal emulator for X; you start it by running `xterm`. `%L` in a compose file refers to the default compose file (see the first link for details).

Comment: I use konsole on kde, so konsole is my xterm ?

Comment: So /usr/share/X11/locale/iso8859-1/Compose in my case ! Where is it defined that I have the locale iso8859-1 (I was looking for fr_BE). And this file already has a <dead_acute> <o> which one takes precedence ?